# Java - how to use Apache Commons IO - BOMInputStream - to remove BOM and parse an XML format URL

Tags: java, xml, parsing, url, apache-commons-io

I tried to use Apache Commons IO - BOMInputStream method to remove BOM and parse an XML format URL. However, the following error

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

remained when running the program.  I have checked the URL link of XML format may contain more than 1 BOM, but I thought the BOMInputStream method should be able to handle them.  Is there some other problems still remain in my code? Appreciate for any help.

p.s. I could use parse the URL using strings--but would like to retain XML format so I could parse the data accurately.

```
public void parseGoogleApi() throws IOException, SAXException,ParserConfigurationException {

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        urlName = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=0005&x=HKG&i=3600&p=10d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v";
        URL u = new URL(urlName);
        HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();                 
        urlCon.connect();
        InputStream iStream = urlCon.getInputStream();
        BOMInputStream bomIn = new BOMInputStream(iStream, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16LE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE,ByteOrderMark.UTF_32LE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32BE);

        Document doc = builder.parse(bomIn); 
        iStream.close();
        System.out.println(doc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `ByteOrderMark.UTF_8` to the list of BOMs to strip.

Comment: Just tried to add UTF_8 but same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This will never work. The content returned for that URL isn't XML.

Comment: Yes thanks for reminding to check the format.  I must have mistaken this url source as another. Thanks!